# How can I summarize multiple string values by a column value in R?

Tags: mysql, r, data-manipulation

OK, so this question isn't as simple as the title may sound. I've got a table that's structued like this:

```
| Brand | First Name | Last Name | Amount  | e-mail              |
|-------|------------|-----------|---------|---------------------|
| A     | John       | Smith     | 920 USD | johnsmith@email.com |
| A     | Mary       | Smith     | 650 USD | johnsmith@email.com |
| A     | Margaret   | Smith     | 400 USD | johnsmith@email.com |
| B     | Eric       | Davis     | 120 USD | jdavis@email.com    |
| B     | Wanda      | Davis     | 500 USD | jdavis@email.com    |
| B     | Jean       | Davis     | 300 USD | jdavis@email.com    |
| A     | Daniel     | Barnes    | 400 USD | dbarnes@email.com   |
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is generate emails to be sent to inform customers of their credit balance, and in the above example, I'd like to send one email to johnsmith@email.com that says something like "You have credits with Brand A. John Smith has 920 USD, Mary Smith has 650 USD, Margaret Smith has 400 USD."

I don't need to get all the way there with this question, but what I would like to do is have one row for each e-mail which somehow includes the information for each row with that email. Maybe some kind of generated concatenated field? It seems simple in theory, but in practice I'm having a tough time coming up with how exactly to do this in R. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Bonus:** I'm also fairly experienced with MySQL, so if there's a better way to do it in SQL, that'd be great!

**Edit:** Dput output (with names and emails edited)

```
structure(list(BRAND = c("R", "C", "C", "C", "C", "R", "R", "C", 
"C", "C"), GUEST_S_LAST_NAME = c("Stockman", "Ericson", "Ericson", 
"Alcin", "Andrews", "Smith", "Smith", "Brown", "Brown", "Brown"
), GUEST_S_FIRST_NAME = c("Margaret", "Abraham", "Naomi", "Dina", 
"Arthur", "Laura", "Alan", "Gregory", "Marina", "Viktoria"), 
    COMPENSATIONAMOUNT_OR_PERCENT = c("920 USD", "1363 USD", 
    "1363 USD", "452 USD", "452 USD", "250 USD", "250 USD", "1019 USD", 
    "1019 USD", "323 USD"), EXPIRATION_DATE = c("04/30/2022 12:00:00 00 am", 
    "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", 
    "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", 
    "04/30/2022 12:00:00 00 am", "04/30/2022 12:00:00 00 am", 
    "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", 
    "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am"), EMAIL = c("email1@email.com", 
    "email2@email.com", "email2@email.com", "email3@email.com", 
    "email3@email.com", "email4@email.com", "email4@email.com", 
    "email5@email.com", "email5@email.com", "email5@email.com"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

your_data %>%
  group_by(BRAND, EMAIL) %>%
  summarize(text = paste0(
    sprintf("You have credits with Brand %s. ", BRAND),
    paste(sprintf("%s %s has %s",
                  GUEST_S_FIRST_NAME,
                  GUEST_S_LAST_NAME,
                  COMPENSATIONAMOUNT_OR_PERCENT),
          collapse = ", "), "."))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   BRAND, EMAIL [5]
   BRAND EMAIL         text                                                     
   <chr> <chr>         <chr>                                                    
 1 C     email2@email… You have credits with Brand C. Abraham Ericson has 1363 …
 2 C     email2@email… You have credits with Brand C. Abraham Ericson has 1363 …
 3 C     email3@email… You have credits with Brand C. Dina Alcin has 452 USD, A…
 4 C     email3@email… You have credits with Brand C. Dina Alcin has 452 USD, A…
 5 C     email5@email… You have credits with Brand C. Gregory Brown has 1019 US…
 6 C     email5@email… You have credits with Brand C. Gregory Brown has 1019 US…
 7 C     email5@email… You have credits with Brand C. Gregory Brown has 1019 US…
 8 R     email1@email… You have credits with Brand R. Margaret Stockman has 920…
 9 R     email4@email… You have credits with Brand R. Laura Smith has 250 USD, …
10 R     email4@email… You have credits with Brand R. Laura Smith has 250 USD, …
```

```
# Data used:
your_data <- structure(list(BRAND = c("R", "C", "C", "C", "C", "R", "R", "C", "C", "C"), GUEST_S_LAST_NAME = c("Stockman", "Ericson", "Ericson", "Alcin", "Andrews", "Smith", "Smith", "Brown", "Brown", "Brown"), GUEST_S_FIRST_NAME = c("Margaret", "Abraham", "Naomi", "Dina", "Arthur", "Laura", "Alan", "Gregory", "Marina", "Viktoria"), COMPENSATIONAMOUNT_OR_PERCENT = c("920 USD", "1363 USD", "1363 USD", "452 USD", "452 USD", "250 USD", "250 USD", "1019 USD", "1019 USD", "323 USD"), EXPIRATION_DATE = c("04/30/2022 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "04/30/2022 12:00:00 00 am", "04/30/2022 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am", "12/31/2021 12:00:00 00 am"), EMAIL = c("email1@email.com", "email2@email.com", "email2@email.com", "email3@email.com", "email3@email.com", "email4@email.com", "email4@email.com", "email5@email.com", "email5@email.com", "email5@email.com")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Dude, I think I love you.